# Error Returning Workbook Object From Function

Tags: vba, excel

When I attempt to return an newly created workbook object from this function I receive an error.  I've seen several posts on SO about this, but most seem to point to using a Variant as a return type and I have been told that's a big no no time and time again.  (Frankly, I don't want to use a variant data type either)

**Error text: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set**. I've seen other posts on SO as well that had errors, but none seem to have been '91'.

```
Private Function NewWorkbook_Open(ByVal clientName As String, ByVal startDateFromSheet As Date) As Workbook

    'Creates/formats new workbook and saves it to the xdrive without any completed
    Dim newWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim activeWorkbookName As String
    Dim formattedDate

    Workbooks.Add

    formattedDate = Replace(Format(startDateFromSheet, "mm/dd/yy"), "/", ".")

    'Saves workbook with new file name with date attached in saveable format
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=XLS_CONFIRM_FILE_PATH & "-" & GetOfficialClientName(clientName) & " " & formattedDate & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal


    NewWorkbook_Open = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
```

The new workbook object is set in the main routine through the following line

`Set newExcelConfirmBook = NewWorkbook_Open(.Cells(rowCounter,sellerFirmColumn).Value, startDateFromSheet)`

Comment: Not sure if this helps but `startDateFromSheet` parameter in the main routine is the same as in your function.

Comment: I believe you are missing `Set` before `NewWorkbook_Open = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use 'active...' if you dont need to. Use the variables you declard correctly.

```
Private Function NewWorkbook_Open(ByVal clientName As String, ByVal startDateFromSheet As Date) As Workbook

   'Creates/formats new workbook and saves it to the xdrive without any completed
   Dim newWorkBook As Workbook
   Dim activeWorkbookName As String
   Dim formattedDate

   Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Add

   formattedDate = Replace(Format(startDateFromSheet, "mm/dd/yy"), "/", ".")

   'Saves workbook with new file name with date attached in saveable format
   newWorkBook.SaveAs Filename:=XLS_CONFIRM_FILE_PATH & "-" & GetOfficialClientName(clientName) & " " & formattedDate & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal


   Set NewWorkbook_Open = newWorkBook

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

How about if you try like this at the end of your code:

```
set NewWorkbook_Open = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
```

Does it work?